# How to tell if my YEN symbol is a backslash or a YEN?

Tags: fonts, backslash

I have a little program which is used to print the backslash symbol to the PDF file. In most English OS a backslash is displayed as a backslash, and my program works just fine. However, in Japanese OS or Korean OS my program starts to have problem. In those OS, a backslash is displayed as a YEN or WON symbol, but my program exports them as a backslash. I know that this is a bug of the font which has been around but i still want to find a solution for it. Does anyone know how to tell if my backslash is displayed like a backslash or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You would not know what character is display by font. They are in same character code `0x5C`

Instead don't use system default font (for eg, ＭＳ Ｐゴシック), 
assign english font for eg, Arial

Or

Use [Unicode backslash ∖](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5#.E7.AC.A6.E5.8F.B7.E4.BD.8D.E7.BD.AE)