# Getting yen symbol when I try to type backslash in pycharm

Tags: symbols

Note: I have been redirected to this website, as it believed to be the appropriate option for questions like this. If this is not the correct website, could someone please just let me know where I can find help?

---

I'm trying to write my program in Pycharm, but for some annoying reason whenever I try to type `\`, it shows up as `¥`.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

this is actually supposed to say `print('\n')`. Whatever has happened has changed all the `\` to `¥` in all my files!

And, yes, I have tried copying and pasting the `\` but it just ends up changing into `¥`

So, could someone please let me know how to fix this??

Comment: as a temporary workaround ```print()``` will do the same thing as ```print('\n')```

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166836/how-to-tell-if-my-yen-symbol-is-a-backslash-or-a-yen

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove appreciate your input (never actually occurred to me). but is there no permanent solution to this?

Comment: I'm reading that backslash in some Korean or Chinese OS's results in a yen or other symbol? Do you have an OS like this?

Comment: No I don't I think I changed my font yesterday and everything was working fine, then today out of nowhere I'm getting this Japanese yen symbol: ¥ instead of \

Answer (score 1):

This could be happening because you are using a font, particularly a Japanese don't. Change the font to an English font like Arial.
If that doesn't work you can use the Unicode backslash in Unicode and ASCII it is encoded at U+005C