# I can't make backward slash "\" in netbeans IDE 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans

Whenever i try to do backward slash in program instead of slash it's making some other symbol and i can't fix it. So anyone can help me?

[image]

Comment: That looks like a Yen currency symbol (`¥`). Possibly helpful: [Getting yen symbol when I try to type backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65587383/12567365). If that does not help, then take a look at [all of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=type+backslash+get+yen+symbol+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Thx dude solution from first link worked :)

Comment: Marking this question as a duplicate of the following: [Getting yen symbol when I try to type backslash in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587383/getting-yen-symbol-when-i-try-to-type-backslash-in-pycharm)